# gettransaction RPC call does not include all balance changes

Tags: bitcoin-core, json-rpc

I am struggling with strange behavior of Bitcoin Core JSON-RPC call `gettransaction`. AFAIK, `.details` array of returned JSON should include all balance changes. If I send some amount to myself (retrieved with `getnewaddress`), it should include both `send` and `receive` elements with the same negative and positive amount respectively.

This behavior is described e.g. in github issue [#4807](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/4807#issuecomment-54081380) and I can confirm that it's a fact in *some* cases.

Hovewer, I noticed a different behavior sometimes. The `.details` array does not include neither `send` nor `receive` elements.

Example:

```
$ bitcoin-cli gettransaction XXX
{
  "amount": -0.1,
  "fee": -0.00002,
  "confirmations": 7967,
  "txid": "XXX",
  ...,
  "details": [
    {
      "address": "SOME_RECIPIENT",
      "category": "send",
      "amount": -0.1,
      "vout": 0,
      "fee": -0.00002,
      "abandoned": false
    }
  ],
  "hex": "..."
}
```

The transaction in mempool.space or other blockchain explorers shows other outputs as well.

```
[
  {
    "value": 0.1,
    "n": 0,
    "address": "SOME_RECIPIENT",
    ...
  },
  {
    "value": 0.05,
    "n": 0,
    "address": "MY_ANOTHER_ADDRESS_1",
    ...
  },
  {
    "value": 0.04,
    "n": 0,
    "address": "MY_ANOTHER_ADDRESS_2",
    ...
  }
]
```

This transaction was constructed with `sendmany` RPC call.

Raw transaction in `.hex` element includes these of course but they are missing in the `.details` element.

Please note that both `MY_ANOTHER_ADDRESS_n` is tracked as `.mine == true` when I call `getaddressinfo MY_ANOTHER_ADDRESS_n`.

Does anyone has an idea why there are no "balance changes" in the `.details` array?

Comment: I filed an issue on Bitcoin Core in [#28555](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/28555)